# Android + Server

Tags: android, android-studio, сервер, webview

У меня есть WebView:

```
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.example.ru/images/Doc/raspor/12-01.pdf");
```

Мне нужно что-бы этот URL я смог менять каждый день на другой.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте строкой массив, и в зависимости от дня недели выдайте значение, которое будет заружаться в ваш WebView.